# get (s)ftp servers system time

Tags: java, ftp

I am stuck with a problem when reading files from an FTP-Server. It appears, that I get empty files. But I know (kind of for sure :-) ) that there are no empty files uploaded. My strong feeling is, that I start downloading when the file has not yet been completely been uploaded.

Unfortunately I do not have the possibility to change the way files are uploaded. So I need to find a workaround from my side.

My Idea was to check the mDate (Last Modification Date) of the file. And when it is more then 30s in the past, it would be safe to start downloading the files. During my tests I uploaded a file and checked the mdate. Unfortunately it was 13s in the future.

**No finally my question**
Is there a way to get the current system time of the ftp server? So I could calculate an offset. In the sftp framework I am using (com.jcraft.jsch) there are function like "getExtension()" but I do not find any usefull information on that method.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Why not check file size before starting download?

Comment: good idea, but I do not know the expected file size.

Comment: Emm, is "empty file" a zero-byte-long file or it's a file filled with zeros or spaces or ...?

Comment: yes, it is zero bytes long. For me, it looks like just the file was created but not yet flushed because upload was in progress when I started downloading.

Comment: Exactly, and this is what you can check before downloading the file. I.e. download the file only it has non-zero size.

Comment: :-) Sometimes life can be so easy. I think I was blind :-)

Answer (score 0):

Before getting files from the remote server, do this. (1) Put an empty file in the remote location. (2) Get the last modified time of the file put in step-1. This roughly gives the system time. (3) List the actual files you want to get, get their last modified time, compare with the system time in step-2. (4) Delete the empty file created in step-1, if you do not like it being there.